# Select Option from Webpage

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find out how to select an option from the option panel from a webpage application. I have tried `driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath)` from the webpage and then run `button.click()`, but somehow when I login to the web application, it doesn't select the path I have set and click the option. Any other way I can do this?

Comment: This is not for a drop down menu.

Comment: Send us the url please